# SpUtility.GetGenericSetupPath returns null

Tags: c#, sharepoint

The following code snippet is expected to return the hive path for SharePoint (..\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14), instead it returns null.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
string featurePath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(string.Empty);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath()` returns the SharePoint hive path based on registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Location`

Could you check it value?

Comment: That registry key returns the following value: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\